undefined reference to ‘OpenSSL_version’ when intalling uwsgi on CentOS
/usr/local/python-3.11.2/lib/python3.11/config-3.11-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.11.a(_ssl.o)：in function ‘sslmodule_init_versioninfo’：
      /root/Python-3.11.2/./Modules/_ssl.c:6090：undefined reference to ‘OpenSSL_version_num’
      /root/Python-3.11.2/./Modules/_ssl.c:6100：undefined reference to ‘OpenSSL_version’

When I tried to run "pip3 install uwsgi" in linux, many like this errors happened and then I failed to install the module. I guess what's wrong with my openssl and faithfully hope someone kind can help me with it. Please

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sorry ,I don' t why the picture I sent was gone
